Altercation on plane about talking on the phone
I'm trying to find this movie.. I think it's a Romantic Comedy.  During one scene (could even be part of the trailer) two girls are on the plane and one of them is on the phone.  The guy across the aisle says something like, "you can't use your phone on the plane".  The friend responds to the extent of "do you work for the FAA? then shut the hell up"
Anyone know this movie?

timeframe? actors? setting? scene? some more detail to help?

I think I remember seeing that.  It was within the last 10 or so years and had some 20-somethings as lead actresses.

I think the movie you're thinking of is She's Out of My League -- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0815236/. Specifically, the scene goes like this:

Passenger: Excuse me. You're not supposed to be on your phone. It's
  bad for the plane. 
Patty: Oh, excuse me? Are you a plane doctor? No?
  So shut the fuck up!


yes!  that's it!  She's Out of My League!
